# C++ class has no member named 'blah'

Tags: c++, header, private

I have a .h file with this in it:

```
#ifndef CS240_LINKED_LIST_H
#define CS240_LINKED_LIST_H

#include <string>

//! LLNode implements a doubly-linked list node
class LLNode {
        friend class LinkedList;
    public:
    
        LLNode(const std::string & v, LLNode * p, LLNode * n) :
          value(v), prev(p), next(n)
        {
        }
    
    private:
        std::string value;        //!< value stored in the node
        LLNode * prev;            //!< pointer to previous node in the list
        LLNode * next;            //!< pointer to next node in the list
};


//! LinkedList implements a doubly-linked list
class LinkedList
{
    public:
    
        //!  No-arg constructor.  Initializes an empty linked list
        LinkedList();
    
    
        //!  Copy constructor.  Makes a complete copy of its argument
        LinkedList(const LinkedList & other);
    
    private:
        //!  two dummy nodes to keep track of the beginning and end of the list.
        LLnode beginning;
        LLnode end;
        int size;
};

#endif
```

In a cpp file I have:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    this->beginning.prev = NULL;
    this->beginning.next = this->end;
    this->end.prev = this->beginning;
    this->end.next = NULL;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
>g++ -o LinkedList.o LinkedList.cpp
In file included from LinkedList.cpp:1:
LinkedList.h:37: error: 'LLnode' does not name a type
LinkedList.h:38: error: 'LLnode' does not name a type
LinkedList.cpp: In constructor 'LinkedList::LinkedList()':
LinkedList.cpp:4: error: 'class LinkedList' has no member named 'beginning'
LinkedList.cpp:5: error: 'class LinkedList' has no member named 'beginning'
LinkedList.cpp:5: error: 'class LinkedList' has no member named 'end'
LinkedList.cpp:6: error: 'class LinkedList' has no member named 'end'
LinkedList.cpp:6: error: 'class LinkedList' has no member named 'beginning'
LinkedList.cpp:7: error: 'class LinkedList' has no member named 'end'
```

I don't know how to fix this. How else would I set the beginning and end objects? Just so you know, I'm a Java programmer learning C++.

Comment: Don't use NULL in C++, use 0 or nullptr if your compiler support it.

Comment: How do you compile your application?

Comment: That is really your header? You need to declare the constructor in the class definition.

Comment: Does your real `LinkedList.h` declare the constructor, too? If not that may be the problem.

Comment: Your class declaration does not declare a constructor -- you need to do that if you want to define your own constructor. I'd try correcting that first and seeing what you get.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I just thought I'd cut out most of the header for the post. I have the constructor in there. I edited the post with more complete code

Comment: @Geoffroy: Why is `0` better than `NULL` in C++? (Assuming that you haven't gone to C++11 and don't have `nullptr`)

Comment: @Carey Gregory: I edited the code to more completely show what I'm trying to compile. The problem is not a missing constructor, but because I left it out of the post everyone thought that was the problem.

Comment: You're going to have to post the *exact* code you have since the code posted would not generate that error.

Comment: By the way, the title of the question does not match the actual error you are getting. The compiler isn't saying beginning/end is not a class member. It's saying that they don't exist in this scope, as if it think you are using those as local function variables (hence why this is not the exact code).

Comment: @Jim Buck: I reposted the exact error emitted by the exact code that I posted. The problem is still basically the same. The compiler can't find 'beginning' or 'end'.

Comment: @Charles Bailey NULL is not always available and is here for compatibility with C. NULL is also a macro corresponding to 0 or 0L depending on the implementation. Thus, if you have a plain C++ file with no include at all, NULL won't be declared.
It's also a story of code-style, whether you like to use macro or not.

Comment: @Geoffroy: `NULL` should be available (if you want to use it) even in a minimal free standing C++ implementation (from `<cstddef>`). If you use it you can document which zeroes you intend to be null pointer constants and which are just zeroes. In theory, this should make moving to `nullptr` easier. I agree that `0` is a perfectly good null pointer constant in C++, but I don't agree that there is a strong argument to prohibit using `NULL` in C++.

Comment: @Charles Bailey I never said NULL is prohibited, just that you should use nullptr instead, or 0 if it isn't available. NULL is only available through including cstddef for example. In all cases, it's better to enable C++0x / C++11 support to have nullptr available

Comment: @Geoffroy: You said "Don't use `NULL` in C++". If that isn't a prohibition, I don't know what is. I'm still not convinced it's anything other than a matter of style or convention in C++03 code.

Comment: It was said as an advice, I don't know if the english imperative could be used like that, if not sorry for the translation problem^^ (in French it does)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You have misspelt `LLNode` as `LLnode`.
- You need to add a default constructor to the LLNode class
- you need to take the address of the `this->beginning` and `this->end` members in the LinkedList constructor:

.

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    this->beginning.prev = NULL;
    this->beginning.next = &this->end;
    this->end.prev = &this->beginning;
    this->end.next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I reposted showing that I had the constructor, but the misspellings and the address thing were important.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the constructor.  Try:

```
class LinkedList
{
    private:
        LLnode beginning;
        LLnode end;
    public:
        LinkedList();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a declaration of `LinkedList::LinkedList()` in the class declaration.

That *should* give you a different error; g++ gave me

```
error: definition of implicitly-declared ‘LinkedList::LinkedList()’
```

Are you sure you've posted the *exact* code you're compiling?  Narrow your code down to something small but complete, and copy-and-paste the exact source files into your question.  (For example, there's no declaration of `LLnode`).  Show us something we can try ourselves.